# Google Drive API update file or folders returns 403

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I'm using `google-api-php-client` and I'm trying to move a folder in the trash. The folder was created from my app, I can upload/create files inside and I can delete it without matters, but I can not call the updete method even on it or any other file/folders.

Those are the scopes that I request at login time: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata

And this is my code:

```php
public function deleteObjectFolder($object, ExternalResource $resource) {
  $folderName = static::buildFolderName($object);

  if (!($client = $this->getClient($resource))) {
    return new Response("refreshTokenExpiredOrTokenRevoked", Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
  }

  $service = new \Google\Service\Drive($client);

  $res = $service->files->listFiles([
    "q" => "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name = '$folderName' and trashed = false"
  ]);

  if (count($res->getFiles())) {
    /** @var \Google\Service\Drive\DriveFile $folder */
    $folder = Util::arrayGetValue($res->getFiles(), 0);
    // $folder->setTrashed(true);
    $folder->setExplicitlyTrashed(true);
    $service->files->update($folder->getId(), $folder);
  }
}
```

Even if I use setTrashed or setExplicitlyTrashed, when the code executes the update method returns this error:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable.",
    "errors": [{
      "message": "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable.",
      "domain": "global",
      "reason": "fieldNotWritable"
    }]
  }
}
```

The same thing appens with a log file inside the folder, also created regularly by the app itself. Code:

```php
[...]
$file = Util::arrayGetValue($res->getFiles(), 0);
$content = $service->files->get($file->getId(), ["alt" => "media"]);
$content = $content->getBody()->getContents();
[...]
$logger = (new FileLogger())
  ->setAction($action)
  ->setDateTime(new DateTimeImmutable())
  ->setLevel($level)
  ->setMessage($message);

$content .= "\n{$logger->toString()}";
$optParams = [
  "data" => $content,
  "fields" => "id",
  "uploadType" => "multipart"
];
$file = $service->files->update($file->getId(), $file, $optParams);
```

Any ideas? Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, from your search query, I guessed that you are using Drive API v3. And, the official document of `explicitlyTrashed` says as follows. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files)

> Whether the file has been explicitly trashed, as opposed to recursively trashed from a parent folder.

I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue. When you want to move the file to the trash box, please use `trashed`. When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
$folder->setExplicitlyTrashed(true);
```

#### To:

```
$folder->setTrashed(true);
```

Or, if the above modification was not useful, how about the following script?

```
$folderId = "###"; // Please set your folder ID of the folder you want to move to the trash box.
$metadata = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(["trashed" => true]);
$service->files->update($folderId, $metadata);
```

#### References:

- [Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files)
- [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)

Comment: I tryied both setTrashed and setExplictlyTrashed but no one worked. The second solution by the way works as a charm! I cannot understand why I have to give new metadata instead of edit the existing ones but it works. Thanks a lot